Which Discount Rate when Valuing Interest Rate Swaps as Forward Rate Agreements
Quick question about interest rate swaps and Forward Rate Agreements (FRAs). In Hull Chapter 4 (Interest Rates), to value an FRA he constructs the following portfolio:
Position 1 (FRA to receive $R_K$ between $T_1$ and $T_2$ which is entered into at $t_0$): $L(R_K- R_M)(T_2 -T_1)$
Position 2 (FRA to pay $R_F$ between $T_1$ and $T_2$ which is entered into at $t_1$): $L(R_M- R_F)(T_2 -T_1)$
where $R_M$ is the actual LIBOR rate between $T_1$ and $T_2$, $L$ is the notional, and $T_1$ is the beginning of the forward period and $T_2$ is the end.
The sum of these portfolios is $L(R_K - R_F)(T_2 -T_1)$ which is non-random and it’s present value can be discounted at the risk free rate from $T_2$, $r_2$ and if we assume the forward rates at $t_1$ are realized ($R_M = R_F$) then the second FRA is worth 0 and the first FRA is worth $L(R_K - R_F)(T_2 -T_1)e^{-r_2 (T_2-t_1)}$.
For swaps, Hull says we can value them as as a portfolio of FRAs.
Using the same argument as above we will value one cash-flow from the swap which is between $T_1$ and $T_2$. From the position of a fixed-rate interest rate swap receiver, define the following:
$R_K$: the fixed rate  in the swap agreement
$R_M$: the actual LIBOR rate between $T_1$ and $T_2$
$R_F$: the forward LIBOR rate between $T_1$ and $T_2$
if we construct the the same portfolio as the above argument for the FRA and assume the forward LIBOR rate between $T_1$ and $T_2$ is realized then we end up with the same non-random payoff $L(R_K - R_F)(T_2 -T_1)$, but instead of discounting at the risk-free rate,Hull discounts at  the LIBOR zero rate. Why does the interest rate change? Why do we not use the risk-free rate  as was done for the FRA?
